# Data do banco de dados retornando 31/12/1969

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Tenho em meu *script* uma chamada para data e ao *printar* para mim me trás uma data de 31/12/1969, e não a data que esta no banco de dados.

Esse é meu Código:

```
@$pag = "$_GET[pag]";
        if($pag >= '1'){
         $pag = $pag;
        }else{
         $pag= '1';
        }

        $maximo = '5'; //RESULTADOS POR PÁGINA
        $inicio = ($pag * $maximo) - $maximo;


  $topico = $_GET['cat'];

  $noticias = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT  id, thumb, titulo, texto, categoria, 'data', autor, valor_real, valor_pagseguro, visitas FROM lp_post WHERE 
  categoria = '$topico' ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT $inicio,$maximo")or die (mysqli_error($conexao));

            if(@mysqli_num_rows ($noticias) <= '0'){
             echo "Nenhuma mensagem encontrada no momento"; 
                }else{

                    $numero = '0';

                  while($res_noticias = mysqli_fetch_array($noticias)){
                    $id = $res_noticias[0];
                    $thumb = $res_noticias[1];
                    $titulo = $res_noticias[2];
                    $texto = $res_noticias[3];
                    $categoria = $res_noticias[4];
                    $data = $res_noticias[5];
                    $autor = $res_noticias[6];
                    $valor_real = $res_noticias[7];
                    $valor_pagseguro = $res_noticias[8];
                    $visitas = $res_noticias[9];
                    $numero ++;




?>
<div class="categoria">
<a href="index.php?topicos=nav/single&amp;topico=<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <h1><?php echo $titulo; ?></h1>

    <span class="info">Data:<?php echo date("d/m/Y - H:m", strtotime($data)); ?> | Autor: <?php echo $autor ?> | Categoria: <?php echo $categoria ?> | Visitas:<?php echo $visitas ?> </span>

      <img src="uploads/<?php echo $categoria ?>/<?php echo $thumb ?>"  class="alinleft" alt="<?php echo $titulo ?>" width="100" height=""/>

    <p class="categoria_p"><?php echo strip_tags(trim(str_truncate($texto, 175, $rep=TRUNC_BEFORE_LENGHT))); ?></p>
  </a>  
</div> 

<?php
    }
 }
 ?>
    <div class="paginator">
<?php

        //USE A MESMA SQL QUE QUE USOU PARA RECUPERAR OS RESULTADOS
        //SE TIVER A PROPRIEDADE WHERE USE A MESMA TAMBÉM
        $sql_res = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM lp_post WHERE categoria = '$topico'");
        $total = mysqli_num_rows($sql_res);

        $paginas = ceil($total/$maximo);
        $links = '5'; //QUANTIDADE DE LINKS NO PAGINATOR

        echo "<a href=\"index.php?topicos=nav/categoria&amp;cat=$categoria&amp;pag=1\">Primeira Página</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";


        for ($i = $pag-$links; $i <= $pag-1; $i++){
        if ($i <= 0){
        }else{
        echo"<a href=\"index.php?topicos=nav/categoria&amp;cat=$categoria&amp;pag=$i\">$i</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }
        }echo "$pag &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";

        for($i = $pag +1; $i <= $pag+$links; $i++){
        if($i > $paginas){
        }else{
        echo "<a href=\"index.php?topicos=nav/categoria&amp;cat=$categoria&amp;pag=$i\">$i</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }
        }
        echo "<a href=\"index.php?topicos=nav/categoria&amp;cat=$categoria&amp;pag=$paginas\">Última página</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
?>
```

O erro dado é a data de 31/12/1696 e não data do banco de dados.

A configuração do banco de dados é timestamp.

Comment: Isso tá com cara de ter um `-1` como valor. OU pode ser erro de sintaxe. Mude o nome da coluna `'data'` usando o *backtick* ` ao invés de aspas simples.

Comment: Da um exemplo da data que vem do banco.

Comment: a data no banco de dados é nesse formato 2015-09-29 14:31:43

Comment: `31/12/1969` aparece quando `date()` não conseguiu parsear data passada, acredito que o erro seja que a sua consulta está retornando a palavra `data` no lugar de `2015-09-29 14:31:43`, como apontando pelo @bigown. Faça um teste do jeito que o código está na pergunta, de um `echo $data;` antes de converter ela.

Comment: @saulo eu vi que você trocou a aceitação de uma resposta para outra. Você fez isto porque queria  ou foi por acidente? Você só pode escolher uma resposta. Votar pode em todas. Veja o [tour].

Comment: @bigown Eu também já tinha percebido e já ia comentar isso... acho que foi por acidente, eu mesmo já fiz isso quando não conhecia o site direito e só queria agradecer todo mundo... :)

Comment: @gustavox eu percebo que quem é novato faz muito isto. Se a pessoa quer escolher outra, é direito dela, mas às vezes não é o que ela quer. Ela fez sem perceber, aí fica "premiado" que recebeu o "voto" por último. Ou seja, é loteria.

Comment: Sim @bigown  e neste caso particularmente parece extremamente errado, porque no primeiro comentário você já tinha dado a resposta, ele aceitou primeiro a sua... enfim, deveria existir um mecanismo pra corrigir este tipo de coisa à revelia do AP, que às vezes não volta e fica mantido o erro/injustiça....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seu problema é que você está usando aspas simples para o campo data `'data'` quando deveria usar a crase

```
`data`
```

Quando o resultset retorna para o php, manda a string `data` fazendo com que a função `strtotime($data)` retorne o primeiro dia referente ao timestamp.

Corrija sua query para:

```
$noticias = mysqli_query($conexao, 
                "SELECT  id, thumb, titulo, 
                         texto, categoria, `data`, 
                         autor, valor_real, valor_pagseguro, 
                         visitas 
                   FROM lp_post 
                  WHERE categoria = '$topico' 
                  ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT $inicio,$maximo") 
              or die (mysqli_error($conexao));
```

Comment: Ok! fiz essa correção e deu tudo certo.Muito obrigado.Valeu.

Answer (score 5):

Já que eu respondi inicialmente no comentário, vou postar aqui.

Para garantir que está falando de um símbolo do banco de dados, como um coluna, por exemplo e não confundir com a sintaxe do SQL é necessário usar o *backtick* (crase). Seu código está usando aspas simples que é o delimitador de um texto. Então o que está sendo usado ali é o texto `'data'`. Quando é tentando interpretar este texto como data, retorna uma data inválida que é um valor anterior ao `01/01/1970`, o início do *timestamp*.

A solução é arrumar a sintaxe.

```
SELECT id, thumb, titulo, texto, categoria, `data`, autor, valor_real,
            valor_pagseguro, visitas FROM lp_post
```

Ou assim que funciona também, afinal `data` não se confunde com SQL neste caso:

```
SELECT id, thumb, titulo, texto, categoria, data, autor, valor_real,
            valor_pagseguro, visitas FROM lp_post
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Date.sql).

Comment: Valeu, deu tudo certo muito obrigado, pela boa vontade de todos vocês que me ajudarão. Muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Inicialmente pensei que podia ser o `echo` chamando `dd/mm/YYYY`, enquanto a data no banco é `YYYY/mm/dd`, mas  o strotime resolve (?) no caso acho né... É que pra converter a data eu fiz [assim](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5367048/4734177), e o código do AP pareceu mais simples... mas só to fazendo este comntário porque queria perguntar o seguinte: no caso então precisa usar o ` ? Não é só deixar sem nada? Eu uso sem e funciona... tá errado? O melhor é incluir as datas com ` no select?

Comment: @gustavox tem razão, melhorei.

Comment: Ah, valeu! Ainda bem que não terei que alterar tudo! ^^